# MongoDB: How best to maintain a live attachment from a db doc to a changing file on the fs?

Tags: index, mongodb

We have a system where users are working with (json) files in a directory, manipulating them directly, possibly moving them around, renaming them, etc. There is also another app outside our control depending on the presence and integrity of these files (so we can't just put them directly in the db).

We'd like to maintain in mongo a metadata document about each file.

Is there a way, using GridFS or something similar, to maintain a live connection between the mongo doc and the file on the file system, even as the user moves the file around?

We're considering capturing fs events to update the mongo doc, but we're worried about the reliability and robustness of such a solution.

Any other thoughts most welcome!

Comment: The only way is have program running background. Program what watch file system change events and make changes to the database according to what has changed. Mongodb itself cannot do that.

Comment: Thank you for the response @JJussi. Hooking into file system events is indeed our best guess for now. We were just hoping someone knows of a battle-tested solution/package or other set of best practices we could pilfer from.

Comment: Available file system hooks will vary depending on the O/S and file system(s) you need to support; suitable solutions/packages will depend on your application/programming environment. A search for "file system notification" with your O/S, file system, and programming language details should turn up some likely candidate libraries to use.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie yeah we’ve used chokidar before (nodejs) and it’s sounding like that’s the direction we’ll be going this time!